# Oracle INSERT into two tables in one query

Tags: sql, oracle

Just wondering if it is possible to run an INSERT into two tables in a single query for Oracle 11g?

I know you can do a INSERT ALL ... SELECT query, but I need to do this without the SELECT as this is data coming straight from XLS into the database.

ideally I'd want something like this example:

```
INSERT INTO table1 t1, table2 t2 
(t1.tid, t1.date, t1.title, t2.tid, t2.date, t2.user, t2.note)
VALUES (1,'01-JAN-15','title',1,'01-JAN-15','john','test note');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Just perform two inserts for each row in the Excel sheet. If you need this to be atomic, you can use a transaction.

Comment: Yeah the 2 INSERTS per entry seems to easy option, but as there will be apx 5,000 entries, I was just wondering if i could stick to 5,000 INSERTS rather than 10,000. But it is a one-off job (hopefully) so if it can't be done then so be it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try to use `from dual;`, like this:

```
INSERT ALL
INTO table1
  (tid, date, title) values (s_tid, s_date, s_title)
INTO table2
  (tid, date, user, note) values (s_tid, s_date, s_user, s_note)
SELECT s_tid, s_date, s_title, s_user, s_note
FROM
( 
    SELECT 
        1 s_tid,
        '01-JAN-15' s_date,
        'title' s_title,
        'john' s_user,
        'test note' s_note
    FROM dual;
)
```

Comment: Interesting, so the INSERT ALL...SELECT but I provide the SELECT data. It works (slightly long query), but it's still inserting into two tables in a single query.  Cheers!

Comment: This worked great for me even with a more complicated structure after the ````INSERT```` clauses: ````WITH cte AS ( ... ) SELECT ... FROM cte````

Answer (score -5):

```
INSERT ALL
INTO table1
  (tid, curr_date, title) values (s_tid, s_date, s_title)
INTO table2
  (tid, curr_date, sys_user, note) values (s_tid, s_date, s_user, s_note)
SELECT s_tid, s_date, s_title, s_user, s_note
FROM
( 
    SELECT 
        2 s_tid,
        '01-FEB-15' s_date,
        'java' s_title,
        'Bablu Gope' s_user,
        'java_note' s_note
    FROM dual);
```

process to execute the above query.

1. copy the query into a file whose extension must be .sql like test.sql
2. connect to database
3. run this command
4. @test.sql